# Unable to generate Docker image using JKube plugin when executing k8s:build

Tags: docker, maven, docker-maven-plugin, jkube

I'm using [Jkube](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/) maven plugin to generate a Docker image via a Jenkins pipeline on AWS EC2 instance under Ubuntu.
When pipeline executes `mvn clean install k8s:build` I'm getting this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.3.0:build (default-cli) on project social-carpooling-frontend: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.3.0:build failed: No <dockerHost> given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' or '//./pipe/docker_engine' and no external provider like Docker machine configured -> [Help 1]
```

And this is the Jenkins pipeline :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Docker Check Stage') {
      steps {
        sh '/home/bitnami/downloads/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin/mvn clean install k8s:build -Premote'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I log using ssh to this machine and execute `docker -v` it says `Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3`

So Docker is really installed and daemon is started, but when I trigger it via maven it seems not to find it !
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the user who's running maven command which doesn't have access to **docker.sock**

The solution is to modify the read/write permission on docker.sock this way :

```
sudo chmod 776 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Bdw, you can also use Eclipse JKube with JIB Build strategy `mvn k8s:build -Djkube.build.strategy=jib`. This comes really handy in CI where you don't need a docker daemon to build+push image to some registry.

Comment: @RohanKumar I think actually the plugin is not supporting Dockerfile mode when using jib strategy because I'm getting this error : 
`Failed to execute the build: Error when building JIB image: Dockerfile mode is not supported with JIB build strategy`

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. Dockerfile mode is not available with JIB. It only works with zero configuration or XML image configuration

Comment: No problem, I switched to XML image config mode and it's fine, but I couldn't find the equivalent for COPY cmd in XML mode !

Comment: We have [assembly mechanism](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin#build-assembly) which generates a single COPY instruction. You can find an example in this [blogpost](https://itnext.io/understanding-kubernetes-maven-plugins-image-xml-configuration-e98ef633e231)

Comment: From v1.4.0 , we would also be able to support multi layers images via XML configuration: https://github.com/eclipse/jkube/pull/724